# Spring Boot JAR built with Maven using requiresUnpack not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I think I have been running into the following issue [Jersey doesn't always work with Spring Boot fat jars](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1468). The workaround should be to set the [Jersey dependencies](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#servlet-app-glassfish) in the `POM` to [`requiresUnpack`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1345#issuecomment-51502294).

My `POM` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.hagstrom</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>
                </configuration>
                <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But I still get the following error when I try to run the JAR that I built with `mvn package`:

```
2017-01-13 10:44:28.229 ERROR 9289 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java%20Programs/springBootDemo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/net/hagstrom/JerseyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [net.hagstrom.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/springBootDemo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
```

Running the JAR that I built in IDE with Artifacts works just fine.

Is there something wrong in my `POM` or the way I build the JAR with Maven?

Comment: I have the same version of spring-boot with the same POM configuration (except: requiresUnpack is not needed). For me /BOOT-INF/ dir is not created in jar but its works. Can you check the .jar file datecreated first and next to open it with gzip and view structure?

Answer (score 2):

This might have been fixed already. I have published a couple of blog posts related to Creating APIs using `Spring Boot`, `Jersey 2` and `Docker` and documenting them using `Swagger` available at: http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html and http://tech.asimio.net/2016/05/07/Documenting-multiple-REST-API-versions-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-and-Swagger.html, both with accompanying source code and I didn't need to `unpack` and `repackage` `Jersey 2` dependencies.

On the other hand, when I was working on the accompanying source code for another blog about [Services Registration and Discovery using Spring Cloud, Eureka, Ribbon and Feign](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/11/14/Microservices-Registration-and-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Eureka-Ribbon-and-Feign.html), I was integrating `Spring Boot` and `Jersey 1` (`Jersey 1` doesn't have a `Spring Boot` starter I do recall to work-around unpackaging `Jersey 1` dependencies a needed to create a multi-module `Maven` project for that specific API service.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using in these examples?

Comment: @g3blv The tutorials involving `Jersey` 2 use `Spring Boot` 1.3.5.RELEASE and 1.3.6.RELEASE.

Comment: I think your blog posts work because you are registering classes one by one. Not use `packages("some.package.to.scan")` method of the `ResourceConfig` class as @mihu86 posted below.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Jersey cannot scan classes in the new "fat boot jar". This occurs when you try to use the `packages("some.package.to.scan")` method of the `ResourceConfig` class.

However, you can achive the same effect using Spring classpath scanning facilities. This way you can scan a package similarily to config.packages():

```java
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Provider.class));
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Path.class));
config.registerClasses(scanner.findCandidateComponents("your.package.to.scan").stream()
            .map(beanDefinition -> ClassUtils.resolveClassName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName(), config.getClassLoader()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Note: please have a look at the source of `org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener`. This is the stock solution and you can see that it does the same: it scans for classes annotated with `@Path` or `@Provider` (but doesn't manage to find anything because of the broken scanning mechanism).

(Using the older version of the boot plugin worked for me too, but I tried to avoid it.)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

> Spring Boot 1.4 changed the internal Jar Structure to facilitate the
>   Spring Boot bootstrap process.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1468#issuecomment-267357809

You can leave this version 1.4.3:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

But spring-boot-jersey fat-jar to be executable without errors it`s need to downgrade plugin version to 1.3.8 like this:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: My understanding is that the workaround to the issue in Spring Boot 1.4 is to use `requiresUnpack` as described just below (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1468#issuecomment-270565789) the comment you are referencing to.

Comment: `requiresUnpack` is fix for different kind of exception like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1345 -> lib/jersey-client-1.11.jar (No such file or directory). But you have /BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory). This can be fixed from spring-boot-maven-plugin (downgrade to 1.3.8) I have the same exception like you and in @ootero example 1.3.8 version of plugin is used. This fix issue for me.